# split column based on 2 columns

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

I have a table in the folowing format:

```
      t_id      date1      date2 date3 email
 100678318 2016-09-05       <NA>  <NA>  natas@gmail.com
 100678319       <NA> 2016-10-05  <NA>  natas@gmail.com
 100732587 2016-11-01       <NA>  <NA>  1000988@boerman.nl
 100689822 2016-09-18       <NA>  <NA>  10@line.nl
 100640340 2016-08-01       <NA>  <NA>  1111tk68@net.nl
 100641415       <NA> 2016-08-02  <NA>  1111tk68@net.nl
```

Now i want to change the data to a different format. (wide)
To eleborate a bit more emails should be grouped to 1 row. And if we have a t_id which occurs more then once we want them to end up like t_id_1 date1 t_id_2 date2 and so forth.

So that the table looks like this (only first record for the example):

```
email             t_id_1      date1        t_id_2      date2      t_id_3 date3
natas@gmail.com   100678318   2016-09-05   100678319   2016-10-05   NA   NA
```

So probably i need some conditional formatting or something. I was hoping for a solution with `Dpylr` and `plyr`.

Try from other questions:

```
library(data.table)
tst <- setDT(tstDF)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) toString(na.omit(x))), by = t_id]
```

Hopefully there is someone with an solution for this problem.

Comment: You want a wide format, not long format. maybe [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format) will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks changed it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The details of `t_id` and `date` are not described in the question so in (1) we have assumed that there are up to 3 `t_id` values per `email` and that they appear in the order corresponding to `date1`, `date2` and `date3` respectively with all other `date` values being NA.  For example, if there are 2 `t_id` values for a particular email then the first one will have `date1` as a date and `date2` and `date3` be NA.  The second will have `date2` as a date and `date1` and `date3` will be NA.  In (2) we assume the same except we generalize to `k` instead of 3.

No packages are used.

**1)** Use `by` to split on `email` and then manually construct the row for each.  Finally `rbind` the rows together.

```
do.call("rbind", 
  by(DF, DF$email, function(x) {
    t_id <- c(x$t_id, NA, NA, NA)[1:3]
    date <- c(na.omit(c(x$date1, x$date2, x$date3)), NA, NA, NA)[1:3]
    data.frame(email = x$email[1], 
               t_id1 = t_id[1], date1 = date[1],
               t_id2 = t_id[2], date2 = date[2],
               t_id3 = t_id[3], date3 = date[3]
    )
  }
))
```

giving:

```
                                email     t_id1      date1     t_id2      date2
10@line.nl                 10@line.nl 100689822 2016-09-18        NA       <NA>
1000988@boerman.nl 1000988@boerman.nl 100732587 2016-11-01        NA       <NA>
1111tk68@net.nl       1111tk68@net.nl 100640340 2016-08-01 100641415 2016-08-02
natas@gmail.com       natas@gmail.com 100678318 2016-09-05 100678319 2016-10-05
                   t_id3 date3
10@line.nl            NA  <NA>
1000988@boerman.nl    NA  <NA>
1111tk68@net.nl       NA  <NA>
natas@gmail.com       NA  <NA>
```

**2)** If desired we could generalize this to up to `k` dates and `t_id` values.  In this case `rbind`/`by` produces a new data frame `long` which has `k` rows for each `email`.  The first row for each `email` in `long` corresponds to the first `tid` and `date` and so on up to the kth.  `long` is subsequently reshaped to wide.

```
is.date <- grepl("date", names(DF))
k <- sum(is.date)

long <- do.call("rbind", 
  by(DF, DF$email, function(x)
    data.frame(email = x$email[1], 
       time = 1:k,
       t_id = c(x$t_id,  rep(NA, k))[1:k],
       date = c(na.omit(do.call("c", x[is.date])), rep(NA, k))[1:k]
    )
  )
)
reshape(long, dir = "wide", idvar = "email")
```

giving:

```
                                    email    t_id.1     date.1    t_id.2     date.2 t_id.3 date.3
10@line.nl.1                   10@line.nl 100689822 2016-09-18        NA       <NA>     NA   <NA>
1000988@boerman.nl.1   1000988@boerman.nl 100732587 2016-11-01        NA       <NA>     NA   <NA>
1111tk68@net.nl.date11    1111tk68@net.nl 100640340 2016-08-01 100641415 2016-08-02     NA   <NA>
natas@gmail.com.date11    natas@gmail.com 100678318 2016-09-05 100678319 2016-10-05     NA   <NA>
```

**Note:** The input `DF` in reproducible form was assumed to be:

```
Lines <- "t_id      date1      date2 date3 email
 100678318 2016-09-05       <NA>  <NA>  natas@gmail.com
 100678319       <NA> 2016-10-05  <NA>  natas@gmail.com
 100732587 2016-11-01       <NA>  <NA>  1000988@boerman.nl
 100689822 2016-09-18       <NA>  <NA>  10@line.nl
 100640340 2016-08-01       <NA>  <NA>  1111tk68@net.nl
 100641415       <NA> 2016-08-02  <NA>  1111tk68@net.nl"

DF <- transform(read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, na.strings = "<NA>"),
          date1 = as.Date(date1),
          date2 = as.Date(date2),
          date3 = as.Date(date3))
```

Comment: Thanks for the very extensive elaboration. I will start trying! Maybe i will come back for some extra elaboration if you want to help me.

Answer (score 2):

I would coalesce into one date variable, then create a counter for each email and then use reshape. This assumes data is sorted by email.

```
library(reshape2)

coalesce <- function(...) {
  apply(cbind(...), 1, function(x) x[which(!is.na(x))[1]])
}

df$date <- as.Date(coalesce(df$date1, df$date2, df$date3), origin = '1970-01-01')
df$id <- 1
for (i in 2:nrow(df)) {
  if (df$email[i] == df$email[i - 1]) {
    df$id[i] <- df$id[i] + 1
  }
}

reshape(df[ c('id', 'date', 't_id', 'email')], idvar = 'email', timevar = 'id', direction = 'wide')
```

Comment: Nice solution indeed, but this only gives me the first 2 t_id's and dates. In my full DF i have around 8 transactions on average. Could you maybe eleborate the for loop a bit more so that i might change the code to my requirements?